# Clearinterval scoped issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

Having issues of removing an interval within the same function.

The code I have set up is as follow:

```js
let $start = document.querySelector('#start');
let $stop = document.querySelector('#stop');

function myFn() {
  let t = event.target.id;

  let logsetInterval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('interval running');
  }, 2000);

  if (t === "stop") {
    clearInterval(logsetInterval);
  }
}

$stop.addEventListener('click', function() {
  myFn()
});

$start.addEventListener('click', function() {
  myFn()
});
```

```html
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
```

I need it to be within the same function...
What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: create your `lgosetinterval` variable ouside `myFunc()` and move your `if` statement above the declaration of `logsetInterval` and remove the `let` from in front of the `logsetInterval` variable (so you are not redeclaring it).

Comment: You'll also need your `setInterval()` in an `else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem sounds like coming from the scope of your function and the global mechanics around it 
Every time you call your function `myFn` a new interval is created, either it's a start or a stop. And it only clear when it's a stop one.

You should probably set your interval as a global variable and only then modify it.

```js
let $start = document.querySelector('#start');
let $stop = document.querySelector('#stop');

let logsetInterval;

function myFn() {
  let t = event.target.id;

  if (logsetInterval) clearInterval(logsetInterval); // if interval already exists, clean it

  logsetInterval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('interval running');
  }, 2000);

  if (t === "stop") {
    clearInterval(logsetInterval);
  }
}

$stop.addEventListener('click', function() {
  myFn()
});

$start.addEventListener('click', function() {
  myFn()
});
```

Hope I understood your problem right